# Dynamically Select/Highlight Specific Rows on a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to dynamically select/highlight a specific row on a `DataGrid` in WPF.

The grid rows are being validated as I iterate through them.  If a row's validation fails then I want the row to be selected/highlighted again so that the user will be prompted to fix the errors.

Which property in the `DataGrid` can I use to select/highlight a row after failed validation?

Answer (score -1):

You wanna try something like this to highlight the row as you iterate through your results:

```
grid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Looks like "Rows" isn't a supported attribute of a DataGrid in WPF.